Does NServiceBus guarantee publishing messages from ASP.NET Core Controller?
I am publishing messages from my ASP.NET Core Controller in response to some synchronous command. If a partial failure happens in between successfully committing my database transaction and NServiceBus actually dispatching my published messages while using outbox, does NServiceBus recover and resend them?
Where can I find the responsible recovery code for this specific scenario in the NServiceBus code repos?
Thank you!

Transactional Session feature is what you're looking for and it's well documented. You'll find details and how to configure it here. This will require enabling the Outbox feature for de-duplication as well.

Hi. I am interested if you can direct me to the classes in NServiceBus code that implement the recovery of outbox message sending on failures.

There's no single set of classes. NSB is a middleware and it acts as an abstraction, and most of the implementation would be under the specific persistence you'll use. If you're looking to understand how it's designed, you'll need to understand NSB pipelines. Or, better, ask that on Particular forum, where the people working on NSB can chime in.
